# If $A$ is finite with $\vert\mathscr{P}(A)\vert=n.$ If $B\subseteq \mathscr{U}$, how many subsets does $B$ have if $B=A\cup\{x\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a given universe $\mathscr{U}$, let $A\subset\mathscr{U}$, where $A$ is finite with $\vert\mathscr{P}(A)\vert=n.$ If $B\subseteq \mathscr{U}$, how many subsets does $B$ have if $B=A\cup\{x\}$, where $x\in\mathscr{U}-A$?

Can anyone guide me through what this question is asking? I'm confused because the author has just introduced power sets, which he defines for any finite set $A$ with $\vert A\vert=n\geq0$, we find that $A$ has $2^n$ subsets and that $\vert\mathscr{P}(A)\vert=2^n$ ..

Im specifically confused about how or why $\vert\mathscr{P}(A)\vert=n$ (unless $n=2^m$ for some positive integer $m$) and does $x\in\mathscr{U}-A=x?$

Comment: It's just a terribly pedantic way of asking what happens to the number of subsets when you throw in a new element. Presumably the answer is to be expressed in terms of $n$. That answer is $2n$: adding a new element doubles the number of subsets.

Comment: And yes, I'm presuming what you are, that $n$ is a power of 2.

Comment: Your parenthetical comment is right on the money: if $|\mathscr{P}(A)|=n$, then $n=2^m$, where $m=|A|$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Oh wow, geez.. so it correct to think of it this way? Every extra $k$ element that is in union with $A$ would increase the number of subsets to $2^{n+k}$ by definition of the power set?

Comment: So long as you start out with a finite set and add in distinct elements, yes.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The point here is that a subset of $B$ is either a subset of $A$ or $x$ union a subset of $A$. So there are twice as many subsets of $B$ as there are of $A$. $|\mathcal{P}(B)|=2n$